Ros2 drone camera projection issue
a few days ago I started working on a project whose aim is to avoid obstacles in the simulation autonomously by the drone and travel from point A to point B. Now I have reached the stage where I want to project points on objects in order to check if everything is in order before creating boundingboxes and later a dataset out of them.
For now, I want to project a point on the middle of the "Construction Cone" object, having the drone in it's initial position when I ran the simulation. The problem I ran into is that, following the logic of my transformation chain, the point seems to be projected incorrectly.
This is my first project that I want you to do using Gazebo and ROS2 (being still in college) and since I haven't found much guidance from anyone else, I thought I could ask here what the solution could be. Besides defining the necessary rotation for aligning the camera with the Z axis of the world and extracting the intrinsic and extrinsic parameters of the camera and the position and orientation of the object, I don't know what else I could miss to make the projection correctly (maybe something else about the axis which I can't figure out). Thank you for possible solutions.
In the image with the projected point (the Cone on which the point must be projected is the first on the right).
Here's the simulation that I'm using: https://github.com/NovoG93/sjtu_drone
import os
import csv
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
from rclpy.qos import QoSProfile
from rclpy.qos import ReliabilityPolicy, DurabilityPolicy
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R
from sensor_msgs.msg import CameraInfo

def calculate_rot_matrix(roll, pitch, yaw):
    # Calculate rotation matrix from Euler angles
    R_x = np.array([[1, 0, 0],
                    [0, np.cos(roll), -np.sin(roll)],
                    [0, np.sin(roll), np.cos(roll)]])

    R_y = np.array([[np.cos(pitch), 0, np.sin(pitch)],
                    [0, 1, 0],
                    [-np.sin(pitch), 0, np.cos(pitch)]])

    R_z = np.array([[np.cos(yaw), -np.sin(yaw), 0],
                    [np.sin(yaw), np.cos(yaw), 0],
                    [0, 0, 1]])

    R = np.dot(R_z, np.dot(R_y, R_x))
    return R


def calculate_transformation_matrix(x, y, z, roll, pitch, yaw):
    R = calculate_rot_matrix(roll, pitch, yaw)
    T = np.array([[R[0, 0], R[0, 1], R[0, 2], x],
                  [R[1, 0], R[1, 1], R[1, 2], y],
                  [R[2, 0], R[2, 1], R[2, 2], z],
                  [0,        0,        0,     1]])
    return T


class ImageSubscriber(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('image_processor')
        # Define a custom QoS profile with the correct access to reliability and durability
        custom_qos_profile = QoSProfile(
            depth=10,
            reliability=ReliabilityPolicy.RELIABLE,
            durability=DurabilityPolicy.VOLATILE)

        # Use the custom QoS profile for the subscription
        self.subscription = self.create_subscription(
            Image,
            '/drone/front/image_raw',
            self.image_callback,
            custom_qos_profile)
        self.pose_subscription = self.create_subscription(
            Pose,
            '/drone/gt_pose',
            self.gt_pose_callback,
            custom_qos_profile)
        self.camera_info_subscription = self.create_subscription(
            CameraInfo,
            '/drone/front/camera_info',
            self.camera_info_callback,
            custom_qos_profile)
        self.bridge = CvBridge()
        self.last_save_time = time.time()
        self.save_interval = 5  # seconds
        os.makedirs(self.image_folder, exist_ok=True)
        self.csv_file = open(self.csv_file_path, 'w', newline='')
        self.csv_writer = csv.writer(self.csv_file)
        # self.csv_writer.writerow(
        #    ["timestamp", "image_name", "object_name", "x", "y", "z", "roll", "pitch", "yaw", "size_x", "size_y",
        #     "size_z", "x_min_bb", "y_min_bb", "x_max_bb", "y_max_bb"])
        self.image_counter = 0
        self.objects_data = {
            "Construction Cone": {
                "pose": [3.440740, 0.667633, 0.049999],
                "orientation": [-0.000002, 0.000002, -0.004192],
                "size": [0.198, 0.198, 0.428696],
            }
        }

        # Camera parameters
        self.horizontal_fov = 2.09  # Horizontal field of view in radians
        self.image_width = 640  # Image width
        self.image_height = 360  # Image height
        self.focal_length_x = self.image_width / (2 * np.tan(self.horizontal_fov / 2))
        self.focal_length_y = self.focal_length_x  # Assuming square pixels for simplicity
        self.c_x = self.image_width / 2
        self.c_y = self.image_height / 2

        # Camera intrinsic matrix (projection matrix) updated
        self.K = np.array([
            [self.focal_length_x, 0, self.c_x],
            [0, self.focal_length_y, self.c_y],
            [0, 0, 1]
        ])

        # Verificare că centrul optic este la jumătatea lățimii și înălțimii imaginii
        assert self.c_x == self.image_width / 2, "Centrul optic X nu este la mijlocul lățimii imaginii!"
        assert self.c_y == self.image_height / 2, "Centrul optic Y nu este la mijlocul înălțimii imaginii!"

        # Verificare că horizontal_fov este setat corect
        assert self.horizontal_fov == 2.09, "Horizontal FOV nu corespunde cu valoarea din URDF!"

        # Initialize extrinsic parameters (will be updated based on drone's pose)
        # self.R = np.eye(3)
        # self.t = np.array([[0.2], [0], [0]])  # Position of camera relative to base_link (0.2 meters forward)

        # Initialize camera parameters with placeholders (they will be updated in callbacks)
        #self.K = np.eye(3)
        self.R = np.eye(3)
        self.t = np.zeros((3, 1))
        # Adăugarea unei noi chei pentru fiecare obiect pentru a stoca matricea de transformare
        for obj_name, obj_data in self.objects_data.items():
            pose = obj_data['pose']
            orientation = obj_data['orientation']
            # Calculăm matricea de rotație folosind funcția calculate_rot_matrix
            R_obj = calculate_rot_matrix(*orientation)
            # Creăm matricea de transformare pentru fiecare obiect
            self.objects_data[obj_name]['transformation_matrix'] = calculate_transformation_matrix(*pose, *orientation)

    camera_transformation = np.eye(4)  # Inițializăm ca matrice identitate 4x4
    camera_transformation[:3, 3] = [0.2, 0, 0]  # Aplicăm translația de 0.2 metri pe axa X

    def camera_info_callback(self, msg):
        # Get the current time for timestamp
        current_time = self.get_clock().now().to_msg()
        self.K = np.array(msg.k).reshape((3, 3))
        # Print the intrinsic matrix and timestamp
        # self.get_logger().info(f'[{current_time}] Parametrii intrinseci updatati (K):\n{self.K}')
        # Print intrinsic parameters
        print(f'Intrinsic Matrix (K):\n{self.K}')

    def image_callback(self, msg):
        try:
            cv_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(msg, "bgr8")
            processed_image = self.project_and_draw_objects(cv_image)
            cv2.imshow("Imagine cu obiecte", processed_image)
            cv2.waitKey(1)
        except CvBridgeError as e:
            pass
            # self.get_logger().error(f"Could not convert ROS Image message to OpenCV image: {str(e)}")

    def gt_pose_callback(self, msg):
        # Extract position
        position = np.array([msg.position.x, msg.position.y, msg.position.z])

        # Extract orientation and convert to rotation matrix
        orientation_q = [msg.orientation.x, msg.orientation.y, msg.orientation.z,
                         msg.orientation.w]
        self.R = R.from_quat(orientation_q).as_matrix()

        # Update extrinsic parameters
        self.t = position.reshape((3, 1))

        #print(f'{self.R} === {self.t.transpose()}')
        #quaternion = np.array([msg.orientation.x, msg.orientation.y,
        #                        msg.orientation.z, msg.orientation.w])
        # Normalize the quaternion
        #quaternion /= np.linalg.norm(quaternion)
        #self.R = R.from_quat(quaternion).as_matrix()

        #print(f"Normalized Quaternion: {quaternion}")
        # print(f"Calculated Rotation Matrix:\n{self.R}")
        # Print extrinsic parameters
        print(f'Position: {self.t.transpose()}')
        print(f'Rotation Matrix:\n{self.R}')

    def project_and_draw_objects(self, image):



        # Obtain the obstacle's position and orientation
        obstacle_data = self.objects_data["Construction Cone"]
        obstacle_pos = np.array(obstacle_data["pose"])
        obstacle_rot = np.array(obstacle_data["orientation"])

        # Calculate transformation matrix from obstacle to world
        transform_obstacle_world = calculate_transformation_matrix(*obstacle_pos, *obstacle_rot)

        # Obtain drone position and orientation
        drone_pos = self.t.flatten()  # Convert from column vector to 1D array
        drone_rot_euler = R.from_matrix(self.R).as_euler('xyz')

        # Calculate transformation matrix from drone to world
        transform_drone_world = calculate_transformation_matrix(*drone_pos, *drone_rot_euler)

        # Invert transformation to get from world to drone
        transform_world_drone = np.linalg.inv(transform_drone_world)

        # Camera offset in drone frame and rotation for camera alignment

        # Camera offset in drone frame and rotation for camera alignment
        camera_offset_drone_frame = np.array([0.2, 0, 0])

        # Assuming the camera is pointing forward along the drone's x-axis, down along the drone's z-axis,
        # and to the right along the drone's negative y-axis, without any additional rotation.
        rotation_matrix_camera = R.from_euler('ZYX', [0, -np.pi/2, 0]).as_matrix()

        # Combine translation and rotation for transformation from drone to camera
        transform_drone_camera = np.eye(4)
        transform_drone_camera[:3, :3] = rotation_matrix_camera
        transform_drone_camera[:3, 3] = camera_offset_drone_frame

        # Project the 3D point into camera space
        point_in_world_space = transform_obstacle_world.dot(np.append(obstacle_pos, 1))

        # Apply the inverse of world to drone transformation
        point_in_drone_space = transform_world_drone.dot(point_in_world_space)

        # Apply the transformation from drone to camera space
        point_in_camera_space = transform_drone_camera.dot(point_in_drone_space)

        # Ensure the Z value is negative before projection, as the camera's view is down the negative Z-axis
        point_in_camera_space[2] = -point_in_camera_space[2]

        # Projection of the point on the 2D image plane using the camera's intrinsic matrix
        point_matrix_2D_homogeneous = self.K.dot(point_in_camera_space[:3])

        # Normalize the 2D coordinates
        if point_matrix_2D_homogeneous[2] != 0:
            point_2D = point_matrix_2D_homogeneous[:2] / point_matrix_2D_homogeneous[2]
        else:
            print("Division by zero in 2D point projection.")
            return image

        # Drawing the point if it's within the image bounds
        if 0 <= point_2D[0] < self.image_width and 0 <= point_2D[1] < self.image_height:
            cv2.circle(image, (int(point_2D[0]), int(point_2D[1])), radius=5, color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=-1)
        else:
            print("The point is outside the image bounds.")

        return image


  #ROS2 Node execution
def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    image_subscriber = ImageSubscriber()
    cv2.namedWindow("Imagine cu obiecte", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)  # Initialize the window
    rclpy.spin(image_subscriber)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()  # Destroy the window when done
    image_subscriber.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

VERSION OF THE CODE AFTER SUGGESTION BY Martin Pecka
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image, CameraInfo
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
from image_geometry import PinholeCameraModel
import cv2
import numpy as np


class CameraNode(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('camera_node')
        self.bridge = CvBridge()
        self.camera_model = PinholeCameraModel()
        self.camera_info_received = False  # Ensure that the camera info is received before processing images

        self.image_sub = self.create_subscription(
            Image, '/drone/front/image_raw', self.image_callback, 10)
        self.info_sub = self.create_subscription(
            CameraInfo, '/drone/front/camera_info', self.camera_info_callback, 10)

        # Window for displaying the processed images
        cv2.namedWindow("Camera View", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

    def camera_info_callback(self, camera_info_msg):
        self.camera_model.fromCameraInfo(camera_info_msg)
        self.camera_info_received = True
        self.get_logger().info("Camera info updated.")

    def image_callback(self, image_msg):
        try:
            cv_image = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(image_msg, desired_encoding='bgr8')
            # Example: Project a point located 1 meter in front of the camera
            point_3d = (1.0, 1.0, 0.0)  # X (forward), Y (left/right), Z (up/down)

            # Check if the camera model is initialized
            if self.camera_info_received:
                u, v = self.camera_model.project3dToPixel(point_3d)

                # Check if the projection result is valid
                if np.isnan(u) or np.isnan(v):
                    self.get_logger().warn('Projection returned NaN values.')
                else:
                    # Drawing a circle at the projected point
                    cv2.circle(cv_image, (int(u), int(v)), 10, (0, 255, 0), -1)
            else:
                self.get_logger().warn('Camera info not received yet.')

            cv2.imshow("Camera View", cv_image)
            cv2.waitKey(1)
        except CvBridgeError as e:
            self.get_logger().error('Failed to convert image: %s' % str(e))


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    camera_node = CameraNode()
    rclpy.spin(camera_node)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()  # Make sure to destroy all OpenCV windows
    camera_node.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Here's my code so far:
https://github.com/4kaws/object_detection_drone/blob/master/README.md?plain=1



It might be worth posting (a snapshot of) your code into the question. This is because code on a Github repo can be a moving target because as you update the repo the code will obviously change. So an issue that you once had (in one particular snapshot) may have been fixed in the future when someone comes to read your question, and so the question you ask now may not make much sense in the future. Hopefully that makes sense.

The https://index.ros.org/p/image_geometry/github-ros-perception-vision_opencv/#humble package provides PinholeCameraModel, which is a class you feed with CameraInfo and it provides you with easy methods to convert between 3D points and pixels in the image. I suggest using this library instead of re-implementing the logic yourself (unless your goal is actually to understand these things).

@MartinPecka Hi, I've tried this but i get something like this: [INFO] [1715271225.968696355] [camera_node]: Camera info updated. [WARN] [1715271225.970514594] [camera_node]: Projection returned NaN values.  I've also updated my code here on this post.

That could mean the point is not visible in the camera.
